# WKWebview:Remove Copy,lookup,share button from Menu and show custom

Tags: wkwebview, uimenucontroller

I want to implement my custom MenuController once user selects a text. I am using the below code to do that, I subclassed WKWebview and implemented below

```
override init(frame: CGRect, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration) {

    super.init(frame: frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
    enableCustomMenu()
}

func enableCustomMenu() {
    let menuController = UIMenuController.shared
    let testmenu = UIMenuItem(title: "Test", action: #selector(test))
    menuController.menuItems = [testmenu]
}
func test(){
    var text = ""
    self.evaluateJavaScript("document.getSelection().toString()") { (data, error) in
        text = data as! String
    }
    print(text)
}
override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    switch action {
    case #selector(test):
        return true

    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

This used to work fine for `UIWebview`, but in `WKWebview`, in the `canPerformAction` we are no longer getting `copy, lookup and share` actions so these guys are not getting removed.

Comment: Did u find any work around for this ?

Comment: Nope unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, I found that you can customize your WKwebview by overriding the function `canPerformAction`
here is an [article](https://medium.com/cs-random-thoughts-on-tech/ios-context-menu-customization-a78bc29f9fc3) about it .

It worked for me!
Hope that help you.

Comment: Links can break. You should [edit] your answer to include the relevant information from the link that answers the original question.